# Rails Migration with adding and removing reference

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

After creating a migration file with `rails generate migration AddClientToUser` I can edit my migration file like so:

```
class AddClientToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.references :client
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove :client_id
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the correct way to reverse the reference column added in the migration?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

that is right! and you could also go with:

```
  def self.down
      remove_column :users, :client_id
  end
```

Comment: Great to know! I wasn't sure if there was some special Foreign Key magic that was made with the reference that would not be cleanly disposed of when the column was simply removed. But wouldn't your example be just `remove_column` not `t.remove_column` ??

Comment: You can also now use the remove_references syntax.

Comment: @BinaryPhile: `remove_reference` (singular) instead of `remove_references`

Comment: @sampi In '12 I believe that was the only api, now singular and plural are both acceptable: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_reference

Comment: Just a note that if you specify all of the details, as in [Zeeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689274/9140970), this migration will be reversible.

Answer (score 86):

Rails 4.2.1

```
rails g migration RemoveClientFromUsers client:references
```

Will generate a migration similar:

```
class RemoveClientFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference :users, :client, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

In addition, one is at liberty to add another or other reference(s) by adding:

```
add_reference :users, :model_name, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

within the very `change` method.
And finally running `rake db:migrate` after saving the changes to the migration, will produce the desired results.

Comment: Works in Rail 5.2 too

Comment: remember to add `type: :uuid`—if that's how you have your ID column setup—for backward compatibility

Comment: In rails 5 and above, you just need to `add_reference :users, :model_name` and index will be added by default

Answer (score 27):

After rails 4 you can do the following

```
class AddClientToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :users, :client, index: true
  end
end
```

It will handle the up and the down for you, as well as creating a foreign key index. You can also use [`remove_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_reference) to do the opposite.

Comment: I've tried this on `rails@4.2.5` with the adapter `mysql2@0.4.2` and it does not work. It throws `needed in a foreign key constraint` mysql error. :(

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 4 you can just type:

> $ rails generate migration AddClientRefToUser client:references

in the console and this will make the same that Ryan said.

Comment: I think it should be `AddClientRefToUsers`

Comment: It can be with or without the s at the end, Rails is smart enough to cover both cases and will generate a change to the users table